# Magento2 - new_grid.phtml

Tags: magento2

I changed `new_grid.phtml` in **vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/widget/new/content/**, but in the frontend nothing changed. I deleted every Cache, reindex everything but it still didnt change anything in the frontend..

[image]

To what Location in my custom theme would I need to copy `new_grid.phtml`, so that it overrides the standard `new_grid.phtml` and why doesn't it change in the frontend even when I'm directly changing the `new_grid.phtml` file?

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your custom theme copy the file to:

```
Magento_Catalog/templates/product/widget/new/content/new_grid.phtml
```

If you definitely don't want the wishlist etc, then you might as well delete the actual code further down the file it is fairly easy to identify.

You may also need to "Flush Static Files Cache"

Comment: I placed it now into the path you told me and removed the whole "addtocart" block from the new_grid.phtml file. After that I flushed every cache (also static files), but still no results? When Im adding a widget with new products on homepage, then It should change there right?

Comment: Turn on template path hints to make sure you have the right template, it might be under the Reports module instead.

Comment: Had the false widget. Found now the right one and it worked :)) thanks alot!!

Comment: Wich is the right one?

Comment: As above, turn on template path hints in developer options to find the correct template.